# Как с помощь mockito можно сделать unit test для класса, который принимает данные из файла json?

Tags: java, json, юнит-тесты, junit, mockito

Есть класс, который выполняят логику деления в столбик, результаты вычисления сохраняются в его переменных.

```
public class IntegerDivisionLogic {

private Integer dividend;
private Integer divisor;
private int quotient;
private ArrayList<Integer> remaindersCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

Дальше, класс IntegerDivisionLogic передает все данные в файл .json

```
    {
  "dividend": 12341234,
  "divisor": 1234,
  "quotient": 10001,
  "remaindersCollection": [
    1234,
    1234,
    1234,
    1234,
    0
  ]
}
```

После, класс рисовалка IntegerDivisionDrawer читает данные из .json занося их в свои поля.

```
public class IntegerDivisionDrawer {

private Integer dividend;
private Integer divisor;
private Integer quotient;
private ArrayList<Integer> remaindersCollection = new ArrayList<>();
```

На основе данных строит алгоритм отрисовки деления.

```
String drawIntegerDivision() {
    buildHead();
    buildBody();
    buildTail();

    return result.toString();
}
```

Надо написать юнит тесты для класса IntegerDivisionDrawer, используя mockito, (говорят так проще всего). Но я не знаю с чего начать писать и как к нему подступится. Для для класса IntegerDivisionLogic тесты написал.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу 2 темы для обсуждения:

1. Дизайн классов
2. Тестирование без mockito

Согласно лучшим традициям ООП ваш класс рисования должен принять готовый объект для рисования и не его ответственность заниматься парсингом json. И как следствие Вам уже не нужно дублировать все поля первого класса, а просто создать поле с типом первого класса:

```
class IntegerDivisionDrawer {
    private final IntegerDivisionLogic logic;

    IntegerDivisionDrawer(IntegerDivisionLogic logic) {
      this.logic = logic;
    }
}
```

Теперь и тестировать можно без mockito.

А чтение и парсинг json оформить можно в отдельном методе:

```
IntegerDivisionLogic getFromJsonFile(String fileName) {...}
```

Теперь на вызывающей стороне будет примерно так:

```
IntegerDivisionLogic logicFromFile = getFromJsonFile("/user/bob/my.json");

IntegerDivisionDrawer drawer = new IntegerDivisionDrawer(logicFromFile);
drawer.drawIntegerDivision();
```

Остаётся открытым вопрос а как же тестировать парсинг json?
Создаёте строку json и передаёте в метод, на выходе ожидаете сконструированный объект. Ничего мокать в этом случае не нужно.